# Django: custom fields not rendering / unbound fields raising error

Tags: django, forms, rendering, custom-fields

I'm trying to have a form generated with custom fields (in a nutshell: a form for someone to respond to a series of questions, part of a Quizz. The Quizz questions are administered using Django admin, now I need to have a form to enable a submission on it).

I understand that in the template file I should be doing a "for field in form" rather than "for field in form.fields".

However, iterating through *form* directly returns an error: *'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'*. This error happens in django's data.get() (called by field.widget.value_from_datadict()) function while trying to render *{{ field }}*.

I understand I'm dealing with unbound fields, but don't see what I'm doing wrong now.
Any clue about the issue?
thanks

## in forms.py

```
class ResponseSetForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, request=None, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = "TOTO"
        quizz = kwargs.pop('quizz')
        super(ResponseSetForm, self).__init__(request, instance, *args, **kwargs)
        question_list = quizz.mcquestion_set.all().order_by('position')
        fields={}
        theChoices=quizz.rating_scale.mcqrating_set.all().order_by('value')
        choices = ((x.value, x.label) for x in theChoices)
        for question in question_list:
            fieldname = 'question_%s' % question.identifier
            widget = RadioSelect()
            self.fields[fieldname] = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, empty_value=None, required=True, label=question.text, choices=choices, widget=widget)
```

## in views.py

```
class QuizzView(FormView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    template_name = 'test.html'
    form_class = ResponseSetForm
    success_url = "/"

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #used by the form
        kwargs = super(QuizzView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({
            'request' : self.request,
            'quizz' : self.quizz
        })
        return kwargs

    def dispatch(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # parse the request here ie.
        self.request = request
        self.quizz = Quizz.objects.prefetch_related('rating_scale', 'mcquestion_set').get(pk=kwargs['pk'])    
        # call the view
        return super(QuizzView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

## in the test.html template file:

```
{% if quizz %}
<form action="/mcq/2/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <h2>{{ form.title }}
    <table>
      {% for field in form %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
          <td>{{ field }}</td>
    </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
{% else %}
    <p>No questions are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

## url pattern is:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)', QuizzView.as_view(), name='run_quizz')
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found the issue: throughout this flow, the form is initialized with the request all the time (i.e. whether a GET or a POST).
Consequently, the form is bound (form.is_bound = True).

So what I did:
- implement a class get() method that sets itself a flag to call for an unbound of the form (I use self.kwargs here but may well use directly a class attribute)
- convey this flag over to the form through view.get_form_kwargs()
- test the flag while in the form. If set, then I make request = None before calling the super **Init**() -> consequently the form has self.is_bound = False

I guess it would be simpler without a class-based view.

Here it is in terms of code:

## in forms.py

```
class ResponseSetForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, request=None, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            quizz = kwargs.pop('quizz')
        except:
            raise Http404
        if 'unbound' in kwargs:
            del kwargs['unbound']
            the_request = request
            request = None
        super(ResponseSetForm, self).__init__(request, instance, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title = quizz.name
        question_list = quizz.mcquestion_set.all().order_by('position')
        choices=list(((x.value, x.label) for x in quizz.rating_scale.mcqrating_set.all().order_by('value')))
        for question in question_list:
            fieldname = 'question_%s' % question.identifier
            widget = RadioSelect()
            self.fields[fieldname] = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, empty_value=None, required=True, label=question.text, choices=choices, widget=widget)
```

## in views.py

```
class QuizzView(FormView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    template_name = 'test.html'
    form_class = ResponseSetForm
    success_url = "/"

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # thekwargs used by the form
        thekwargs = super(QuizzView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        thekwargs.update({
            'request' : self.request,
            'quizz' : self.quizz
        })
        if 'unbound' in self.kwargs:
            del self.kwargs['unbound']
            thekwargs.update({'unbound': "Yes"}) # we want to let the form know that he is not actually bound
        return thekwargs

    def dispatch(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # parse the request here ie.
        self.request = request
        self.quizz = Quizz.objects.prefetch_related('rating_scale', 'mcquestion_set').get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        return super(QuizzView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs.update({
            'unbound' : True,
        })
        # the below call triggers a call to get_form_kwargs (and call to form)
        return super(QuizzView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: In my context, that probably makes class-based views not really suitable compared to a good old function.